# SyntaxError: bad input on line 16 in main.py in trinkets

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
import turtle
    
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(10000000000)
pen.color("green", "red")
pen.begin_fill()
     
for i in range(100):
    pen.forward(209)
    pen.left(421)
    pen.right(312)
pen.hideturtle()
turtle.done()
   
o == input("Do you love it?y/n")
  **if o == y:**
      print"Thanks, please love for me{^-^}"
    if o == n:
      print"Thanks for playing{^-^}"
    else:
    
    
      print"I can't understand what are you saying, can you say that again?
```

[Here is the link](https://trinket.io/library/trinkets/79d7e039a4)

In line 16 syntax error.
I made it in trinket.
My first project.
I put it in trinkets.
In steamforVietNam weekly Challenge

Comment: Indentation Problem

Comment: Also, ```print("I can't understand what are you saying, can you say that again?")```

Comment: And, ```o = input("Do you love it?y/n")```

Answer (score 0):

1. `==` and `=` are different. `==` is for comparison. `=` is for assignment.
2. Are you using python 2.7? It should be  `print("I can't understand what are you saying, can you say that again?")`
3. When you want to compare strings, **make sure to use a** `' '` or `" "`

```
import turtle
    
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(10000000000)
pen.color("green", "red")
pen.begin_fill()
     
for i in range(100):
    pen.forward(209)
    pen.left(421)
    pen.right(312)
pen.hideturtle()
turtle.done()
   
o = input("Do you love it?y/n")
if o == 'y':
    print("Thanks, please love for me{^-^}")
elif o == 'n':
    print("Thanks for playing{^-^}")
else:
    print("I can't understand what are you saying, can you say that again?")
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Sujay mentioned, you have problems with:

- identation
- print statement syntax
- assigning variables

Also, if you're planning to use the user input in some way (not clear what you'd like), put it above the turtle pen:

```py
import turtle

o = input("Do you love it?y/n")
if o == "y":
    print("Thanks, please love for me{^-^}")
if o == "n":
    print("Thanks for playing{^-^}")
else:
    print("I can't understand what are you saying, can you say that again?")

pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(10000000000)
pen.color("green", "red")
pen.begin_fill()
 
for i in range(100):
    pen.forward(209)
    pen.left(421)
    pen.right(312)
pen.hideturtle()
turtle.done()
```